# How to set height 100% div in div.row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: red">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color: green; height: 100%">
     <img src="http://www.unixstickers.com/image/data/stickers/jsfiddle/JSfiddle-blue-w-type.sh.png"  class="img-responsive img-circle center-block" style="width: 20px">
  </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color: blue">
     22222222222 <br />
     22222222222 <br />
     22222222222 <br />
     22222222222 <br />
     22222222222 <br />
     22222222222 <br />
     22222222222 <br />
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/t814cmts/

How can I set height 100% for first div in div.row? Why height:100% not working? I know - I can set height with px, but my site must be responsive and I don't want set px for all devices.

I want height 100% because I would like to center the image to the text on the right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: Your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t814cmts/4/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is percentage height not working on my div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728022/why-is-percentage-height-not-working-on-my-div)

Comment: You can use flexbox to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your image in left div should be centered to right div containing text. So even your content div increases in height, your image in left div should be centered vertically?
I tried this match height javascript to match height the adjacent elements, take a look at the URL http://brm.io/jquery-match-height-demo/